# Magento 2.1.6 : Configurable product is not added to cart

Tags: magento-2.1, configurable-product, addtocart

Im recentrly create a configured product (Size Attribute : S, M , XL)  `Catalog Input Type for Store Owner Swatchtext`.

when i select Any one of the `size [S] [M] [L]`   Click `add to cart` page will be redirct to  `Url:www.xxxmagento/checkout/cart/`.

Not Added any item in my Cart.

Comment: have you find a solution for it?